# Non Gui Jmeter graph

Tags: jmeter, performance, jmeter-plugins

I am searching for Jmeter plugin or existing listener for graph result

I would like to have Graph(s) against elapsed time
Label-number of users against elapsed time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **"jp@gc - Active Threads Over Time"**.

For Details: See Here--> [Active Threads Over Time](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=ActiveThreadsOverTime)

Hope, this will satisfy your query. Thanks!!